# Getting Promise Data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

This question has been asked many times but after reading all the responses, mine still doesn't work and I think it has something to do with the scope of the variable.

I am trying to make a request and return it's result back into the main scope but it either returns undefined or a promise even though the promise has already been fulfilled.

```js
const getLastMessage = fetch("/history?id="+getChatID())
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((messages) => {
    return messages[messages.length-1]['id']
    // returns correct result
  })

const getLastFetched = async () => {
  lastMessage = await getLastMessage
  // sets lastMessage to correct value
};

let lastMessage = getLastFetched()
console.log(lastMessage)
// undefined
```

If I make `getLastFetched` return data to `lastMessage` it will return a promise object.
I tried this exact same thing previously and it worked?

Comment: Hmm, the other answers didn't cover this? You simply can't expect an async operation to somehow be synchronous.

Comment: I'm sure the exact same thing didn't work previously.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running the code in async block, you should add `await` before `getLastFetched()`. Also, that will return an empty promise because getLastFetched doesn't return anything. So even if last message will get declared, id doesn't matter because at the time of console log it's empty. The last thing is, lastMessage should be declared before getLastFetched.

```
const getLastMessage = fetch("/history?id="+getChatID())
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((messages) => {
    return messages[messages.length-1]['id']
    // returns correct result
  })

let lastMessage;

const getLastFetched = async () => {
  lastMessage = await getLastMessage
  // sets lastMessage to correct value
};

await getLastFetched()
console.log(lastMessage)
```

This is how it would work inside of async IIFE block:

```
(async () => {
  const getLastMessage = fetch("/history?id="+getChatID())
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((messages) => messages[messages.length-1].id);

  let lastMessage;

  const getLastFetched = async () => {
    lastMessage = await getLastMessage
    // sets lastMessage to correct value
  };
    
  await getLastFetched()

  console.log(lastMessage);
})();
```

Comment: How would I actually run the IIFE block? When I just add it in, it gives undefined error because I'm guessing that block of code never ran.

Comment: Also I'm not running it in an async block

Comment: In order to use async/await you need to run it inside an async block. I don't know the full context of your app/problem. This is just a fragment of your code. That's why I used it here. IIFE stands for Immediately-invoked Function Expression which executes right away. I highly recommend you to check out how promises and async functions work in JavaScript or share full code so we can investigate it further.

Comment: I just put the entire code within the block where I put the request so I didn't have to deal with promises. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect last message to be anything but undefined for 2 reasons. That part is not going asynchronously, only inside of `getLastFetched` is. And you are not returning anything in that function.

I'd also not mix and match `await` and `.then`. This would be one way to solve it:

```js
(async () => {
  const getLastMessage = async () => {
    const request = await fetch("/history?id="+getChatID());
    const data = request.body;
    return data[data.length-1]['id']
  };

  const getLastFetched = async () => {
    lastMessage = await getLastMessage();
    return lastMessage;
  };

  let lastMessage = await getLastFetched();
  console.log(lastMessage);
})();
```

Comment: How would I actually run that? When I just add it in, it gives undefined error because I'm guessing that block of code never ran.

Comment: @walker This should work fine on itself. When I tested it in Codesandbox, it was working without a problem. The async function that it's wrapped in is executed by those `()` at the end. So this part of code is probably not the issue. Aside from that, you would not get anything if it did not run at all. Just check what's inside `const data = request.body` you might need to adapt what you return there.

Comment: I just put the entire code within the block where I put the request so I didn't have to deal with promises. Thanks anyways!